# OnCompleteListener values turn to null

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to download a subcollection in my firebase database and save the document ids to an arraylist called emails. The download seems to work however the values all turn to null after the onComplete ends. I call set methods to set my class variables however it does not seem to work
Here is a picture of my data base.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF9Uw.png)

```
package com.example.eventfeed.eventFeed;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.eventfeed.login.ActivityLoginEmail;
import com.example.eventfeed.model.Person;
import com.example.eventfeed.model.Post;
import com.example.eventfeed.profiles.Profile_girl;
import com.example.eventfeed.profiles.Profile_guy;
import com.example.eventfeed.profiles.Profile_guy1;
import com.example.eventfeed.R;
import com.example.eventfeed.signup.RegisterActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Source;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;

public class PeopleGoing extends Activity {

    private DocumentReference mDocRef ;
    private CollectionReference docRefEventGoers ;
    private FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    private StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
    private StorageReference coverPhotos;
    private StorageReference profilePics;
    private ImageView cover_photo;
    private ImageView profile_photo;

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private RecyclerView postList;
    private PeopleGoingAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private  static String email;
    private  static String name;
   private LinkedHashMap<String,Person> people = new LinkedHashMap<String, Person>();
   private ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();

private static String value;

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmails(ArrayList<String> emails) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getEmails() {
        return emails;
    }

    public  static String  getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void  setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public static String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.people_going_window);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        // or other values
        if(b != null) {
            value = b.getString("event");
        }



       docRefEventGoers = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("events/"+ value+"/atendees");
        docRefEventGoers.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
                        temp.add(document.getId());
                        setEmails(temp);

                    }


                }

            }
        });
```

EDIT
The data does get downloaded
[temp download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcVVY.png)

However after the the oncomplete ends emails is empty even though setEmails is called
[empty emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MahAL.png)

EDIT2: Still could not figure out the problem, for anybody with the same issue, I worked around it by putting all the functionality I needed within the oncomplete listener. Definitely not an optimal solution but good enough if you're in a pinch.

Comment: 1)check if your path from collections is ok.2) debug your code

Comment: @android I added some screenshots to show that the path is correct and the data gets downloaded. However, it does not get saved to my class variable

Answer (score 0):

This is too much for a reply comment, but you might be dealing with a pointer issue. Seems odd though. Let's consider the following potential.

You are dealing with a pointer.

You are creating a pointer with a life scope equal to your callback.

You are then setting your local pointer to that variable. Then you are going out of scope. Visualize this (possible, but unlikely scenario).

```
-->callbackScope
------>tempArray
-------->addItems
------>emailArray = tempArray memory location
-->outofScope -> tempArray garbage collection = null
aka emailArray was garbage collected = null

-->classScope
------>myEmailArray = tempArray
```

To fix this, you may need to create and add the elements to the class scoped array.
Give that a shot, let me know if that fixes you, if not I'll remove this answer, just wanted to give you something to try that wouldn't fit in a comment.

Try this:

```
 ArrayList<QueryDocumentSnapshot> myResults = task.getResult()
 for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : myResults){
     getEmails().add(document.getId());
 }
```

Comment: I think i grasp most of what you're saying. However, I'm not sure how i would go about solving the problem. Would the email array I have not already be a class scoped variable. I declare it as a private variable. Then create the tempArray within the callback and use the setMethod to set the class variable. (Also as a side not I have read that Firebase calls like the one I am using can be asycnhronous, I'm not sure if that could be related to your answer.)

Comment: Hi Kolby, try my update and see if that makes sense to you, btw, I don't think this is a memory pointer issue, but it sure sounds like it is, so worth a shot. If this fixes it, that would lead me to believe it was.

Comment: Still no luck. Emails has the right value in the onComplete but goes to empty afterwards. I tried to debug through it to see when it changes but the for loop seemed to go on forever.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then see if maybe you are getting multiple onComplete callbacks. You may have to unregister yourself after the first callback as a last resort if that is happening

Comment: That gave me an incompatible types error. 
Required:
java.util.ArrayList
<com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot>
Found:
com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot

Comment: It was pseudo my friend lol. I didn't know what type of list you are getting back. Simply command click into the getResult and see what the left variable should be and correct the type.

Comment: I believe task.getResult() returns a single QuerySnapshot not a list. But i did assign it to myResults and put it in the for loop but still no luck.

Comment: I would need more info about how your task is working. So should you be doing a "While getTaskResult has value" rather then assuming it is there. Maybe add some logs and see what's happening, what's in each loop iteration etc.. that will give more clues as to what is going on